# ReadAllLines and split to string array

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to build an application that will load a txt file into a database using SQL. I am good on the SQL side, but getting the C# to work has been tough. I have this command running on a button click. I want to get the parsed data into the database, where I will SQL to modify it.

I am currently stuck on a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error, which I receive at the line `command.Parameters["@num2"].Value = items[1];`

Data looks like this:

```
SECURITIES|ERROR CODE|NUM FLDS|PX_LAST|
ASWABUND Curncy|0|1|44.665000|
BCOMTR Index|0|1|162.554200|
BP0001M Index|0|1|.251630|
BP0002M Index|0|1|.270380|
BP0003M Index|0|1|.296810|
BP0006M Index|0|1|.438130|
 ...etc....
```

And my code is this:

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=LAPTOP-LLSEHUPE;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
                          + "database=tempdb"))
        {
            string sqlscript1 = "CREATE TABLE ##Temp_BBG_Daily " +
                "( [Temp_Ticker] Varchar(max) NULL, " +
                "  [Temp_Field2] int NULL, " +
                "  [Temp_Field3] int NULL, " +
                "  [Temp_Value] Varchar(max) NULL) ";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlscript1, connection);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ##Temp_BBG_Daily ([Temp_Ticker],[Temp_Field2]," +
                "[Temp_Field3],[Temp_Value]) " +
                "VALUES (@num1, @num2, @num3, @num4)";
            command.Parameters.Add("@num1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@num2", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@num3", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@num4", SqlDbType.VarChar);

            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\WORK\\Project\\NNL_PH_SNAP1800.20170620 - Copy.txt");
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < allLines.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] {'|'});
                    command.Parameters["@num1"].Value = items[0];
                    command.Parameters["@num2"].Value = items[1];
                    command.Parameters["@num3"].Value = items[2];
                    command.Parameters["@num4"].Value = items[3];
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: `allLines[i]` before `.split` presumably is not what you think, perhaps its empty? set a breakpoint and see what it is.

Comment: You may be processing an empty last line. Simply add `if (items.Length > 3) { ...` after the `items = ` assignment.

Comment: @PeterB that worked 100%, thanks